# JQuery slider appearing when initially selected and not sliding - IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, slider

Good Afternoon,

I am having an IE9 issue and was hoping that there may be somebody out there that can assist. 
In FF, and IE10+, slider effect works fine and functions normally.

Issue:
I have a nested div, one hidden, one shown. 
When I initially roll over the outerDiv, the innerDiv appears without the slide effect. Any repeated roll over actions, the innerDiv appears/disappears with the slide effect and functions normally.

Expected Result:
I want to get the slide effect to work with the initial rollover in IE9.

I've tried .slideToggle and  .animate without success.

I'm thinking that it has something to do with timing...calling the div before it exists in the DOM, but I can't put my finger on it.

Any assistance provided will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

HTML

```
<div id="outerDivTest" class="circle outerDiv">
  <div id="innerDivTest" class="innerDiv">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, populo sadipscing id nam.
  </div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$("#outerDivTest").addClass('visible').show("scale",{},'slow');

$(".outerDiv").on("mouseenter", function() {
  $("#innerDivTest").addClass('visible').slideDown(1000);
});

$(".outerDiv").on("mouseleave", function() {
  $("#innerDivTest").addClass('visible').slideUp(1000);
});
```

CSS

```
#outerDivTest {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  background-color: #29abe2;
  border-width: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 100;
}

#innerDivTest {
  top: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.visible {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if the reason is because the document isn't fully loaded yet then just wrap it in document.ready:

```
 $(document).ready(function ()
   {
     $("#outerDivTest").addClass('visible').show("scale",{},'slow');

     $(".outerDiv").on("mouseenter", function() {
        $("#innerDivTest").addClass('visible').slideDown(1000);
     });

     $(".outerDiv").on("mouseleave", function() {
       $("#innerDivTest").addClass('visible').slideUp(1000);
     });
   }
 );
```

Comment: Then it's not because the document isn't loaded.

Comment: ok. So does anybody have an idea as to why it's not sliding on initial hover? Subsequent hovers work fine.

Comment: tried your code in jsfiddle and it's just coming back with a circle around the text in developer mode on both IE Edge and IE 9

Comment: your jsfiddle just shows a ball that swipes to a different color once you mouse enter/leave it. I opened it in IE/IE9/firefox with same results. There is no slider, it's just a ball.

Comment: It doesn't do anything (slide, swipe) when you first mouse over it.  When you mouse leave, it swipes, when you mouse back over it, it swipes.  How do I get it to swipe when you initially mouse over it?